# Angular ng-grid pinned header not static on first page load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

Whn I initially load the page with my ng-grid and then resize the grid columns so that I need to scroll horizontally to see all of them, the first column doesn't stay static. Once I refresh the page, the grid loads column settings from localstorage and then the first col stays static. I'm using a custom headerCellTemplate, and I have enablePinning: true, and first column pinned: true already set up. I'm trying to figure out how to get the first column to stay static on the initial page load.

Code:

```
var headerTemplate = '<div class="ngHeaderSortColumn test" ng-style="{\'cursor\': col.cursor}" ng-class="{ \'ngSorted\': !noSortVisible }">'
+ '<div ng-click="col.sort($event)" ng-class="\'colt\' + col.index" class="ngHeaderText"  popover-append-to-body="true" popover-trigger="mouseenter"'
+ 'popover="{{getTooltip(col.displayName)}}">'
+ '{{col.displayName}}</div>    <div class="ngSortButtonDown" ng-show="col.showSortButtonDown()"></div>'
+ '<div class="ngSortButtonUp" ng-show="col.showSortButtonUp()"></div>'
+ '<div class="ngSortPriority">{{col.sortPriority}}</div>'
+ '<div ng-class="{ ngPinnedIcon: col.pinned, ngUnPinnedIcon: !col.pinned }" ng-click="togglePin(col)" ng-show="col.pinnable"></div></div>'
+ '<div ng-show="col.resizable" class="ngHeaderGrip" ng-click="col.gripClick($event)" ng-mousedown="col.gripOnMouseDown($event)"></div>';

var adverseEvent = {
    field: 'event_label',
    width: '28%',
    pinned: true,
    visible: true,
    displayName: 'Adverse Event',
    headerCellTemplate: headerTemplate,
    cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText pull-left">{{row.getProperty(col.field) }}</div>'
};
```

...more columns below, not relevant

Function that sets gridColumns:

```
function getCustomGridColumns(stateName) {
    var storageId = stateName + exports.GRID_STORAGE_ID;
    var gridColumns = localStorageService.get(storageId);
    if (!gridColumns) {
        gridColumns = getDrugCostColumnDefinition();
        localStorageService.set(storageId, angular.toJson(gridColumns));
    }
    return gridColumns;
}
```

Get grid columns

```
function getDefaultGridOptions() {
    return {
        data: 'gridNumbers',
        enableSorting: true,
        enableColumnResize: true,
        showGroupPanel: true,
        enableCellGrouping: true,
        showColumnMenu: true,
        enablePinning: true,
        showFilter: true,
        jqueryUITheme: true,
        columnDefs: 'headers',
        sortInfo:{fields:['metric_sum_event_cost'], directions:['desc']},
        plugins: [new ngGridFlexibleHeightPlugin({"maxHeight": 500}), new ngGridCsvExportPlugin()],
        showFooter: true,
        footerTemplate: 'app/common/partials/footer-template.html',
        footerRowHeight: 43
    }
};


// watch when any column settings changed from grid settings and saved into localstorage
$scope.$watch('drugCostGridOptions.$gridScope.columns', functionChangeGrid, true);

// callback for watchers
function functionChangeGrid(newVal, oldVal) {
    var config = [];
    angular.forEach(newVal, function (col) {
        config.push(_.pick(col, 'field', 'displayName', 'width', 'visible', 'headerCellTemplate', 'cellFilter', 'cellTemplate', 'pinned'));
    });
    drugCostsService.setCustomGridColumns(currentState, config);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue - looks like my pinned column needs to have a width defined in pixels, not percentage:

```
var adverseEvent = {
    field: 'event_label',
    width: '300',
    pinned: true,
    visible: true,
    displayName: 'Adverse Event',
    headerCellTemplate: headerTemplate,
    cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText pull-left">{{row.getProperty(col.field) }}</div>'
};
```